# Context menu of toolbar icon doesn't work

Tags: release-freya, applications, menu, wingpanel

I have Elementary OS Freya on my desktop computer. I installed some applications, which appear in toolbar (dropbox, steam, xneur, ...). But when I open an context menu from toolbar icon and select any item, then nothing happens. Sometimes it repeats with language indicator. What's wrong?

P.S. I think I found the cause of the problem. I tried to open the menu options via right-click. Left mouse button works successfully. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: the context menu works only with the mouse button that was used to trigger the menu in the first place. looks like a bug