# Left and right click on panel icons shows the same context-menu that works only if clicked with the same mouse button that triggered the menu

Tags: release-freya, wingpanel, icons, mouse, menu

Unlike in panels that look similar from other desktops (Ubuntu Unity, Cinnamon, etc), **left and right clicking the panel icons shows the same menu** options. This is true for 'systray' icons of all applications (Skype, uGet, Dropbox, Kazam, Clementine, VLC etc) as well as for system options icons on the panel (keyboard layout, volume/sound, network, battery, etc).

But **clicking an option in the menu does not work unless it is done with the same mouse button that was used to show the menu in the first place**.

There seem to be two odd things here:

1. right or left click on the same panel icon shows exactly the same menu with the same options
2. once the menu is shown, the selection cannot be done anymore with the left click in all cases, but only if the icon was left-clicked in the first place.

This is a problem sometimes because it is common behavior in all desktop environments and all operating systems that I have used (Linux but also Mac and Windows) to be able to left-click on a menu that was triggered with a right click on a panel or tray icon (also when right-clicking the Plank dock icons), and I am very used to that and find it annoying to click again on many occasions: while right-clicking a panel icon seems normal behavior, and a menu appears as expected, in order to use that menu one has to continue right-clicking inside the menu too.

In the gif below: that's what happens in the following cases:

- menu triggered by left-clicking on the keyboard layout icon, left-click on the menu (option followed); then, menu triggered by left-clicking on the keyboard layout icon, right-click on the menu (option not followed)

OR

- menu triggered by right-clicking on the keyboard layout icon, right-click on the menu (option followed); menu triggered by right-clicking on the keyboard layout icon, left-click on the menu (option not followed)

[image]

**Is this a setting that can be adjusted somehow? - Or, if a bug, is there some way to change this behavior?**

---

In fact the description above should be adjusted a bit: left or right clicking **anywhere** in the 'systray' area (in fact the [Ayatana Indicator](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/4227/170)) brings forth a context-menu and then one can move the mouse on that panel area and different context-menus will be shown for the different applications/applets. For all such context-menus the behavior described above will appear: only the mouse button that was initially used to click on that panel area can be used to select an option within **any** of those context-menus.

[image]

Comment: reported in a more limited form here: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/4465/170

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this was ever posted as a bug, but looks like one, which I sorrily can no longer investigate for I am in Loki, where the problem is utterly absent as the 'tray' panel area is administered by a different application. More [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/4227/170). Also [here](http://blog.elementary.io/post/145881464631/loki-beta).

Comment: Please post bugs on the bugtracker. This here is not a bug tracker and it is likley that no developer will see it here.

Comment: @Djax - right you are. The qustion is old and your comment is to my recent so called answer. Now I am already in Loki and it makes no point for me. Should I delete it?